# SSIS 2005 XML to Database

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, xsd

My problem is, I need to get the attribute name and character data from the XML. SSIS generates the XSD, but the output is not what I expected. Is it possible to get the character data from this XML, or should I just load the XML into field through the script task. I eventually have to get the data in a table format.

I have this XML.

```
<GeneralActivity CustomizedType="Visit">
<Field APIName="ID">32211465</Field>
<Field APIName="ExID">999</Field>
<Field APIName="Status">Submited</Field>
<Field APIName="Type">Visit</Field>
<Field APIName="Title">Test Title</FIeld>
</GeneralActivity>
```

I connected to it through an XML Source and generated the XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="GeneralActivity">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Field">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="APIName" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="CustomizedType" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My output to a flat file is...

```
ID,
ExtID,
Status,
Type,
Title,
```

I need my output to be...

```
ID,32211465
ExtID,999
Status,Submited
Type,Visit
Title,Test Title
```

Comment: So read the file into a table, then query it?

Comment: Is it safe to say 2005 can't do what I need? I see it being done in 2008 here. http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/04/07/loading-xml-using-ssis/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way, feel free to comment.
This is what works for me now. I'm sure I'll have to adjust as I go.

I created an SSIS package that loops through the XML files that need to be picked up. One at a time, I call two stored procedures.

The first one, I created using this resource. [SQL 2005 XML Import](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/06/18/60235.aspx)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ithc_InsertVisits
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @fileName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC('
            INSERT INTO ithc_VisitsXML(xmlFileName, xmldata, xmlStatus)

            SELECT ''' + @fileName + ''', xmlData, 0
            FROM
            (
                SELECT  * 
                FROM    OPENROWSET (BULK ''' + @fileName + ''' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS XMLDATA
            ) AS FileImport (XMLDATA)
        ')

END
GO
```

Which gives me these results.
[image]

Then, the next store procedure is called to get the data in table format. The table has all of the XML attributes stored as nvarchar(max).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ithc_InsertVisitsPopulate
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
BEGIN

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @loopCount          INT
    DECLARE @recordID           INT
    DECLARE @columnName         NVARCHAR(128)
    DECLARE @dataType           NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @strSQL             NVARCHAR(MAX)

    DECLARE @fieldValue         NVARCHAR(MAX)

    --Create a record in Visits so that we can update that record
    INSERT INTO ithc_Visits(xmlid)
    SELECT id FROM ithc_VisitsXML WHERE xmlstatus = 0

    CREATE TABLE #TableFields
    (
        id int not null identity,
        COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(100),
        DATA_TYPE   NVARCHAR(10)
    )

    --Insert Tasks to temp table
    INSERT INTO #TableFields (COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE)
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
    FROM Information_Schema.Columns 
    WHERE Table_Name = 'ithc_Visits'
            AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'ID'
--  ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME

    CREATE TABLE #temptable 
    (
        id INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
        fieldName VARCHAR(100), 
        fieldValue VARCHAR(100),
        xmlID BIGINT
    )

    INSERT INTO #temptable(fieldName, fieldValue, xmlID)
    SELECT r.value('@APIName', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Field1
            , r.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Field2
            , id
    FROM ithc_VisitsXML
        CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('/GeneralActivity/Field') AS x(r)
    WHERE xmlstatus = 0

    --Set a loopCount for while loop
    SET @loopCount = 1

    --Use the while loop to check if we have any fields left to go through
        while ( exists(SELECT id FROM #TableFields WHERE id = @loopCount) )
            BEGIN

                --Get current record in temp table
                SELECT  @columnName     = t.COLUMN_NAME,
                        @dataType       = t.DATA_TYPE,
                        @fieldValue     = v.fieldValue,
                        @recordID       = v.xmlID
                FROM #TableFields t
                    JOIN #temptable v ON
                        t.id = v.id AND
                        t.COLUMN_NAME = v.fieldName
                WHERE t.id = @loopCount
                -----------------------------------------------------------         

                SET @strSQL = 'UPDATE ithc_Visits SET ' + @columnName + ' = ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @fieldValue) + ''' FROM ithc_Visits WHERE ID = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @recordID)
                EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL, N'@columnName varchar(128)', @columnName = @columnName


                DELETE FROM #TableFields WHERE id = @loopCount

                SET @loopCount = @loopCount + 1
            END

    UPDATE ithc_VisitsXML
    SET xmlStatus = 1
    WHERE id = @recordID

    DROP TABLE #TableFields
    DROP TABLE #temptable
END
GO
```

Which gives me these results. (sample set)
[image]